# Setting AdaptiveTrigger.MinWindowWidth to TemplateBinding causes the trigger to never execute

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

Currently I have this code in one of my custom controls inside generic.xaml

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNarrow">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger x:Name="VisualStateNarrowTrigger" MinWindowWidth="{TemplateBinding VisualStateNarrowMinWidth}" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PART_SPACER.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNormal">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger x:Name="VisualStateNormalTrigger" MinWindowWidth="{TemplateBinding VisualStateNormalMinWidth}"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters/>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Where `VisualStateNarrowMinWidth` and `VisualStateNormalMinWidth` are DependencyProperties with the type of int, for example:

```
public int VisualStateNarrowMinWidth
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(VisualStateNarrowMinWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VisualStateNarrowMinWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStateNarrowMinWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(VisualStateNarrowMinWidth), typeof(int), typeof(PageHeader), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));
```

Setting the MinWindowWidth to an integer like 0 for narrow and 521 for normal makes it execute just fine. How would I make binding work with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to the TemplatedParent, like this:

```
<AdaptiveTrigger x:Name="VisualStateNarrowTrigger" MinWindowWidth="{Binding VisualStateNarrowMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```